# DTD flash open source engine?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, dtd

DTD flash flex action script open source engine?

I need some open source engine for creating some games like [Desktop Tower Defense games](http://www.handdrawngames.com/DesktopTD/Game.asp)

Does it exist?)

So… What do I need? I need -

• Open Source Libs

• Tutorials

• Blog posts/Articles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a framework for specifically writing a DTD game but you could look into using the [pushbutton engine](http://pushbuttonengine.com). It has a fair amount of nice features and should get you up and running faster than starting from scratch...

[Download](http://pushbuttonengine.com/download/)

[Docs](http://pushbuttonengine.com/docs/)

Hope this helps - you should update this question for the url of your game when you get it built!